# Placing Inner Join Linq Query Into View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

Viewmodel:

```
public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users> users;
public IEnumerable<Telephone__Search.Models.tbl_pics> images;
public IEnumerable<Telephone__Search.Models.tbl_locations> branches;
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = from a in db.tbl_users
                where a.userid == 6
                select a;

    var branchjoin = (from e in db.users
                      join c in db.tbl_locations on e.address equals c.location
                      where e.userid == 6 && e.emp_address == c.location
                      select c).ToArray();

    return this.View(new ViewModel
                     {
                         branches = branchjoin // Error here
                         users = users,
                     });
}
```

How do I out `c.location` into razor view within MVC? The most common error I get is can't do conversion from `IQueryable` to `System.Generic.Collection`. The error is stated within the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.ToArray()`, with `.ToList().AsQueryable()`, does this do the trick?